# Image as child in Container don't follow Container border

Tags: flutter

the problem is that image edge is visible and don't follow the border that I set for Container.

```dart
Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[900],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
              ),
              child: Image(
                image: NetworkImage(thisSongInfo.albumImageUrl),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                color: Colors.black87,
                colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
              ),
),
```

the fit: BoxFit.contain fix the edge problem but this not cover the container

Comment: try foregroundDecoration of Container instead of decoration

Comment: Try adding height and width to the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the image with a `ClipRRect`, more info on the docs here 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html ,

Try this code:

```
Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[900]
                      ),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
                          child: Image(
                            image: NetworkImage(thisSongInfo.albumImageUrl),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            color: Colors.black87,
                            colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
                          )),
                    )
```

Comment: If it answered your question, please accept as answer, so that people also searching for this question will know, and other people will not bother looking for other solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want rounded corner image you can use `"ClipRRect"` widget

```
ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              child:  Image(
                image: NetworkImage(thisSongInfo.albumImageUrl),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                color: Colors.black87,
                colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
              ),
         )
```